# Algorithm for maintaining a transformation matrix stack in graphics

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 2d, sdl

I am trying to write a small 2D graphics library using SDL. I want to implement the equivalent of the Matrix stack in openGL and implement functions like pushMatrix() and popMatrix() in openGL. I can do all the coding for matrix multiplications. But the need the algorithm for storing that stack and managing the transformations.

Comment: Since this is tagged C++, you could always use `std::stack <...>`. No point re-inventing the wheel if you do not have to, though stacks are one of the first data structures they teach in CS :)

Answer (score 1):

A stack is essentially an array, or a linked list, where the PUSH operation creates a copy of the last/topmost element and appends it at the end, and the POP operation removes the last element from the list/array.

Using/Implementing arrays/linked lists is basic computer science knowledge.